# Deployment Groups configure the Yaml Pipelines

Tags: deployment, agent

I want to run a particular powershell script on all agent machines in a given pool. How can I get a list of agents from the given pool? I am already able to do that in classic pipelines through deployment groups; how do I achieve the same functionality in YAML pipelines?

Deployment group how to configure.